# How to capture the generic type of a generic constraint?

Tags: dart

Consider the following generic class:

```dart
class Foo<T extends Bar<dynamic>> {}
```

How can I obtain the generic argument of `Bar` at compile time?

I would expect the following code to print `int`, but it prints `dynamic`:

```dart
class Bar<T> {}

class Foo<T extends Bar<dynamic>> {
  Foo(this.value) {
    _debugBarType(value);
  }

  final T value;

  void _debugBarType<A>(Bar<A> value) {
    print(A);
  }  
}

void main() {
  Foo<Bar<int>>(Bar());
}
```

---

I know I could do:

```dart
class Foo<A, Bar<A>> {}
```

But I would like to define the `Foo` class using a single generic parameter instead of two.

Comment: What is the problem with two generic parameters anyway?

Comment: Pointless repetition. Having to type `Foo<A, Bar<A>>` doesn't bring anything.

Comment: Well, it does give you the ability to have control over the type. Clearly, the compiler does not infer the type of your generic constraint. You will have to use two generic parameters. Seems like a reasonable solution.

Comment: It's not. In my case, it'd _always_ be a duplicate. Anyway, it looks like the upcoming extension types would allow that.

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not possible to do on *any* class.

There's currently a pending feature request on Dart to support such use-case: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/620

It's worth noting that there's a workaround if you can add a method on the class concerned.

For example, say you have a generic class `Model<T>`:

```dart
class Model<T> {
  T value;
}
```

Then you can add a "capture" method as such:

```dart
class Model<T> {
  T value;

  R capture<T>(void cb<P>(P value)) => cb<T>(value);
}
```

This then allows you to write:

```dart
void someFunction<T extends Model<dynamic>>(T model) {
  model.capture(<P>(value) {
    // `P` will be the captured type instead of `dynamic`
  });
}
```